# @Observable initial value with classes

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable, swift-macro

Converting from `ObservableObject` to [`@Observable`](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10149) macro, an initial value is required but initializing from `init` fails:

```swift
@Observable final class ViewModel {
    var foo: Foo // ❌ @Observable requires property 'foo' to have an initial value (from macro 'Observable')

    init(foo: Foo) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}
```

The macro seemingly requires initialization twice (with an initial value that will be immediately discarded). Is there a reasonable solution to this using classes for view models?

Comment: Best to just use the View struct for your view data as it's designed

Comment: @malhal That is neither what this question is about nor the use case provided for `@Observable` (see the talk I linked)

Comment: @amg you the talk you linked is about "Simplify your SwiftUI data models with Observation." your question has code for a ViewModel which is what the View struct is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually seems like a limitation of the language itself. The [SE-0400](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0400-init-accessors.md) evolution proposal aims to tackle this exact problem.

The proposed solution is already implemented on the `main` branch of the Swift toolchain behind the experimental feature flag `InitAccessors`, so if you want to play around with it, you can by switching to the `main` branch version of the toolchain and enabling this feature flag.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a workaround for this problem without the proposed compiler changes being accepted and released.